# Not returning the next biggest value in my array

Tags: php

I have an array with a bunch of military times listed and I am trying to find the next closest value up to the current time. For example when it is 9:30 am it should return 9:40 am because that is the next biggest time but instead it will return 10:00 am no matter what time it is.

```
function closest($array, $number) {
sort($array);
foreach ($array as $a) {
    if ($a >= $number) return $a;
}
return end($array);
}

$array = array(0730,0750,0810,0830,0840,0850,0900,0910,0920,0930,0940,0950,1000,1010,1020,1030,1040,1050,1100,1110,1120,1130,1140,1150,1210,1230,1250,1310,1330,1350,1410,1430,1450,1510,1530,1550,1610,1630,1650,1710,1720,1730,1740,1750,1800,1810,1820,1830,1840,1850,1900,1910,1920,1930,1940,1950,2000,2010,2020,2030,2040,2050,2100,2120,2140,2200,2220,2240,2300,2320);
$number = date("Hi");
$nexttime = closest($array, $number);

echo date("g:i a", strtotime("$nexttime"));
```

I have been through it many times trying to diagnose the problem, Trying to remove all of the zeros in front of the first few times returned an even stranger result of 7:00 pm.

Comment: fyi prefixing a number with `0` tells php to interpret it as octal.

Comment: Did you try to output the array after the sort using print_r?

Comment: it seems it returns always end($array)

Comment: I see what both of you guys are saying using print_r on the array with leading zeros returns the array with values from the 0th to 11th as 0. But with out them it is fine. Could it be because the $number is being set to a number with a zero in front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an error with your array and prefixed numbers:

> Parse error: Invalid numeric literal in (*line number of array*)...

You can define the values on array as string and cast them on the function with `(int)`. See the following solution:

```
<?php
function closest($array, $number) {
    sort($array);
    foreach ($array as $a) {
       if ((int) $a > $number) return $a;
    }
    return end($array);
}

$array = array('0730','0750','0810','0830','0840','0850','0900','0910','0920','0930','0940','0950',1000,1010,1020,1030,1040,1050,1100,1110,1120,1130,1140,1150,1210,1230,1250,1310,1330,1350,1410,1430,1450,1510,1530,1550,1610,1630,1650,1710,1720,1730,1740,1750,1800,1810,1820,1830,1840,1850,1900,1910,1920,1930,1940,1950,2000,2010,2020,2030,2040,2050,2100,2120,2140,2200,2220,2240,2300,2320);

$nexttime = closest($array, '0930');
echo $nexttime;
```

**Demo:** http://ideone.com/TceTRb

Answer (score 0):

Numbers with leading zero are treated as octal numbers, 0730 for example is 472 in decimal. If an invalid digit such as 9 is given in an octal integer, the rest of the number is ignored.

Either store your list of digit numbers as one long string then use `explode()` to convert it into an array and or put a quotation mark around the 4-digit value to define each element of array as string then use `(int)` for proper type casting in the function.

```
<?php
function closest($array, $number) {
sort($array);
foreach ($array as $a) {
    if ($a >= $number) return $a;
}
return end($array);
}

$string="0730,0750,0810,0830,0840,0850,0900,0910,0920,0930,0940,0950,1000,1010,1020,1030,1040,1050,1100,1110,1120,1130,1140,1150,1210,1230,1250,1310,1330,1350,1410,1430,1450,1510,1530,1550,1610,1630,1650,1710,1720,1730,1740,1750,1800,1810,1820,1830,1840,1850,1900,1910,1920,1930,1940,1950,2000,2010,2020,2030,2040,2050,2100,2120,2140,2200,2220,2240,2300,2320";
$array=explode(",", $string);
$number = date("Hi");
$nexttime = closest($array, $number);
echo $nexttime;
```